# "No AspNetMount URI for request" error in Apache

Tags: asp.net, apache

I've installed `mod_aspdotnet-2.2.0.2006.msi`, and modified the `httpd.conf` to support dot net:

```
LoadModule aspdotnet_module "modules/mod_aspdotnet.so"
AddHandler asp.net asax ascx ashx asmx aspx axd config cs csproj licx rem resources resx soap vb vbproj vsdisco webinfo

<IfModule mod_aspdotnet.cpp>

AspNetMount /active "E:/TestWeb"

Alias /active "E:/TestWeb"

# Allow asp.net scripts to be executed in the active example
<Directory "E:/TestWeb">
    Options FollowSymlinks ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    DirectoryIndex default.htm default.aspx index.html index.aspx
</Directory>
# For all virtual ASP.NET webs, we need the aspnet_client files
# to serve the client-side helper scripts.

AliasMatch /aspnet_client/system_web/(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)/(.*) "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v$1.$2.$3/ASP.NETClientFiles/$4"

<Directory "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v*/ASP.NETClientFiles">
    Options FollowSymlinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

</IfModule>
```

**It works fine when I launch normal HTML files(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:801/test.html), but when I launch any asp.net file(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:801/apps.aspx), there comes 500 error:**

> Internal Server 
>   Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, xxx@gmail.com and inform them
>   of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that
>   may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

- [Mon Aug 11 11:20:41 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.25 (Win32) mod_aspdotnet/2.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
- [Mon Aug 11 11:20:41 2014] [notice] Server built: Jul 10 2013 01:52:12
- [Mon Aug 11 11:20:41 2014] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4952
  httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx for ServerName
- [Mon Aug 11 11:20:41 2014] [notice] mod_aspdotnet: CorBindToRuntimeEx has loaded version v2.0.50727 of the .NET CLR engine.
  httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx for ServerName
- [Mon Aug 11 11:20:42 2014] [notice] Child 4952: Child process is running
- [Mon Aug 11 11:20:42 2014] [notice] Child 4952: Acquired the start mutex.
- [Mon Aug 11 11:20:42 2014] [notice] Child 4952: Starting 64 worker threads.
- [Mon Aug 11 11:20:43 2014] [notice] Child 4952: Starting thread to listen on port 801.
- **[Mon Aug 11 11:20:56 2014] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_aspdotnet: No AspNetMount URI for request: /Apps.aspx**

This is the first time I use Apache to run my asp.net site. Maybe the error is stupid but please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

In my config, I used alias
`Alias /active "E:/TestWeb"`. So I should input url `http//172.0.0.1/active` instead of `http//172.0.0.1`.